# Is the way I am using rdtsc: atomic

Tags: c++

I am using a `x64` machine with C++ code

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" lo), "=d" (hi));
```

Where lo and hi are unsigned `ints` and store the 32 bit value of the clock counter.  Will lo and hi be stored atomically, or is it possible that due to the case when lo overruns and increments hi I get one of the values representing before the roll over and one after, which would result in a count that is either 2^32 too low or 2^32 too high (depending on which one was captured first).

Comment: I am under the impression that you must use a serializing instruction (e.g. CPUID) to guarantee order here.

Comment: Use the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic function and skip the inline assembler.